# What are the best non-flickering (zero-flicker), dimmable bulbs for an enclosed glass fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, dimmer-switch, bulb, halogen

I have a glass-enclosed bathroom wall fixture wired to a separate wall dimmer (on the opposite wall).  I need to replace the bulb, but the old incandescent bulbs no longer exist. I could easily replace the incandescent dimmer switch with an LED dimmer switch.

***However, there is a secondary issue that I need to address*** (in addition to heat considerations):

***Some people are very sensitive to a 60 Hz flicker.*** It may be a visual sensitivity, or it may be an EMR sensitivity.

And the more one dims the bulb, the shorter the duty cycle and the more apparent the flicker.

Can anyone comment on this phenomenon, and suggest ways to mitigate its effects?

Can I safely replace the old bulb with a halogen bulb (that has the old bulb form-factor)?

(Note that I also need to be able to dim the bulb all the way down to double as a night-light, and not have it go out if there is a slight variation in line voltage or current).

Comment: This question would be much better if you were to [edit] to ask "what features do I look for to find a bulb that is less likely to flicker". As it stands you're asking for product recommendations, which is off-topic. You do have a couple of good answers to the "what features" question already.

Answer (score 2):

Halogens are essentially the same as regular incandescents as far as energy use. In general, I find that LEDs have less flicker than fluorescents, but I am not super-sensitive to 60 Hz flicker. Long-term, for most applications, LEDs are the way to go.

My recommendation:

- Stick to name-brand, UL/ETL listed dimmers and bulbs. The shortcuts (on dimmers and bulbs) made by low-end brands are more likely to lead to flicker, dimming problems, early failure, etc. Because both parts (unless you rewire for low-voltage lighting) are using 120V, safety is critical. But there are some cheap dimmers and bulbs that are safe enough to be UL or ETL listed but are still "junk". When it comes to bulbs, one additional certification to look for is [DLC](https://www.designlights.org/qpl/). DLC is not a guarantee, but it is a good indicator of quality products.
- Obviously make sure that the dimmers say LED-compatible and the bulbs say dimmable.
- Look for CRI of 90 or above - higher is better.
- Color temperature is a bit subjective. If you got a lighting store or at least some big box stores you can see a bunch of different bulbs lined up and compare temperature to find what you like.
- Some dimmer manufacturers have lists of compatible bulbs and some bulb manufacturers have lists of compatible dimmers. Not being listed does *not* mean they won't work together (hard for a manufacturer to test everything) but being listed is a good indication that they will work together.

Unless you have a real need for extras, I would avoid WiFi and other fancy stuff - just get a quality top-brand dimmer.

Answer (score 1):

### Triac dimming was hokey from day one

The popular method of 120V dimming is called "triac dimming".  It was invented to be cheap.  It was extremely marginal on the day it was invented, to be used with incandescent bulbs, and the *forced adaptation* to LEDs has only been more compromised and kludge-infested.

Obviously you prefer it because it's easy to slap together with supplies from the local box store, but then, you get all the compromises.

### Special needs require special tech

You should move to one of the more competent dimming schemes.

**0-10V dimming** is a commercial method of signaling the desired dimming level on a separate set of wires. Each fixture uses its own dimming method. Whether the fixture flickers or respond well to being *very dim* will vary by fixture.

**PWM Dimming** is used only on low voltage DC (12V or 24V) lighting in which the whole system (switch/dimmer and fixtures) run on low voltage DC from an extrenal source.  PWM dimming operates at extremely high frequency e.g. 3000 Hz and will not be visible.  Further, PWM dimming is able to go to extremely low brightness levels.

With LED lighting, existing wiring can easily handle the higher current required for low voltage DC.  Therefore PWM controls on low voltage lighting is probably your best answer. This is not easy to implement, however, since it requires a DC power source.